# Javascript store in session, get from session in python/flask

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I am working with a flask app, and am trying to store a Json object using javascript, and retrieve it in python as i would like to store a sort of "shopping list" information that the user is generating, into my database. The object appears in my browsers session storage

[image]

but it seems my syntax is off as im getting "KeyError: 'routine'"

```
 @app.route("/workoutroutines", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def showWorkoutRoutines():
    """Show all workout routines, allow user to create new routine"""
    
    if session['routine'] is not None: // <---error here
       try: 
        obj = json.loads(session['routine'])
        print(obj.name) 
     
       except: 
           print("something went wrong")
        



    all_routines = WorkoutRoutines.query.all()
    createRoutineButton = url_for("createARoutine")
    return render_template("allRoutines.html", all_routines=all_routines, createRoutineButton=createRoutineButton)
```

error log:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\Springboard\workoutApp\venv\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2088, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\Springboard\workoutApp\venv\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2073, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\Springboard\workoutApp\venv\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2070, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\Springboard\workoutApp\venv\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1515, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\Springboard\workoutApp\venv\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1513, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\Springboard\workoutApp\venv\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1499, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**req.view_args)
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\Springboard\workoutApp\app.py", line 171, in showWorkoutRoutines
    if session['routine'] is not None:
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\Springboard\workoutApp\venv\Lib\site-packages\flask\sessions.py", line 79, in __getitem__
    return super().__getitem__(key)
KeyError: 'routine'
```

Comment: please add the error log to the question, the error you mentioned seems to be coming from line `obj = json.loads(session['routine'])` instead of the line you commented at

Comment: My mistake, I have updated the OP, the same error happens when trying
if session['routine'] is not None:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting a key error because when you write

```
session['routine']
```

Your code is trying to access the key 'routine' in the session object but it's not there, so it's throwing a key error.

You could modify it to:

```
if 'routine' in session:
    obj = json.loads(session['routine'])
    print(obj) 
else:
    print('your error message')
```

Within flask you can also see what keys are in the session object by doing:

```
app.logger.info('Session keys: {}'.format(session.keys()))
```

I don't think flask logs stuff at info level by default, so for this to work you need to set logging to info level when you start your app. If that's too fiddly just replace 'app.logger.info' with print.

Comment: Thank you this does solve the key error, it seems flask still does not recognize the 'routine' being in my session however

Comment: Glad to help! Hmm if you're running a development version of the flask app and you can see the session in your browser (i.e. at 127.0.0.1) that the means the flask app has created a session so I think it will have to be there somewhere... What happens when you print out the session variable? Have you set a secret key and assuming you've imported session from flask at the top of the script.

Comment: I created the original session key in javascript session storage. Luckily, I was able to post another question and a user informed me that javascript and flask session storage are 2 entirely different entities, so this explains why 'routine' does not exist when flask tries to access it. 

I do have the secret key and import session in my app.py as well. Im going to try a few more methods to see if i can come up with a solution and will report back here if i find one